How the heck do liquids work?
Liquids are denser than gases with similar molecular weight, which seems to indicate a strongly attractive intermolecular force; on the other hand they have a negative Joule-Thomson coefficient which indicates a repulsive force! How is this possible? is there some strange interplay between repulsive and attractive forces I am not aware of?

For quite a few properties, liquids are closer to solids than to gases. The intermolecular attraction is actually usually weak, and way weaker than the quickly increasing repulsive forces from when you try to compress them even further. I'm not sure why you are surprised.

Molecules tend to attract but are repelled at close spacing. The effects manifest themselves in the behavior of all real gases and condensed matter. The topic seems to be too vague or large in scope to be addressed in a reasonable length on this site.

@naturallyInconsistent are the intermolecular forces at stp generally repulsive or attractive on average?

@Harrychink in a liquid the intermolecular forces are zero on average because the intermolecular spacing is the distance at which the short distance repulsion and long distance attraction balance out. This is a key difference from gases where the molecules are kept apart by their thermal motion not by repulsive forces.

I'm not sure how you would do a Joule-Thompson expansion with a liquid. Presumably you'd have to compress it first then suddenly remove the compressive force and let it expand back to its original volume. In this case it's obvious that the force acting is repulsive.

Please add a link to a source for the negative Joule-Thomson coefficient of liquids.

@john if they are zero on average then should’nt entropic forces make the liquid expand ?

@david https://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/jun2000/959891423.Ph.r.html

@Harrychink why would entropic forces make the liquid expand? Liquids aren't like gases, where the intermolecular forces are very small. In liquids the forces dominate the behaviour and keep the intermolecular distance approximately constant.

@john, didn’t you say the intermolecular forces are net 0

@Harrychink the net force is zero at the intermolecular spacing, but if the decrease the spacing the force becomes strongly repulsive while if you increase the spacing the force becomes strongly attractive. To a good approximation for small displacements the potential is quadratic with displacement away from the equilibrium spacing i.e. like a very stiff spring with a relaxed length equal to the intermolecular spacing.

@john Well, to balance entropic forces, there would need to be a net attractive force at stp, correct?
